# Rails cannot install gem 'unf'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Whenever I try: `$ gem install unf`,  I get this error :

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
```

I even tried adding these libraries

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core     zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison
```

but no cigar, any idea what I should do ?

Comment: try once with ... "gem update -system"

Comment: this happens due to corrupted cached specs, so u may also need to remove the existing empty or corrupted gemspecs for "unf" gem.

Comment: gem update system gave me this ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::AmbiguousOption)  ambiguous option: -system

Comment: ohh sorry... try with "gem update --system", double hyphen before "system"

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM=TRUE gem update --system
```

worked